# Trouble to create Cloudwatch Metric & Alarm - Check if statement was logged in last 24 Hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to create an Cloudwatch Alarm via Terraform to get an Alarm if an sheduled Tasks in AWS did not run like expected.

**Terraform**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "update_run" {
  name           = "update_run"
  pattern        = "Database was updated"
  log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.log_group.name

  metric_transformation {
    name          = "update_run_count"
    namespace     = "dbupdates"
    value         = 1
    default_value = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "update_run_alarm" {
  alarm_name          = "update_run_alarm"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "update_run_count"
  namespace           = "dbupdates"
  period              = "86400" // 24 h
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "1"
  treat_missing_data  = "ignore"
  alarm_description   = "Number of db updates done"
  alarm_actions       = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.alarms.arn}"]
  ok_actions          = ["${data.aws_sns_topic.alarms.arn}"]
}

data "aws_sns_topic" "alarms" {
  name = "alarms"
}
```

The tasks runs at 04:00 AM via CloudWatch sheduled events. I want an alarm when ""Database was updated" was not seen in the last 24 Hours.

Current situation: We get an Alarm an 1 minute later "OK" .. i guess the way we want to archive this is totaly wrong (-: When does the "Period" starts to count? maybe after Terraform creates the Alarm?

Would love to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the CloudWatch console.
2. Choose Metrics.
3. Choose the All Metrics tab.
4. Choose Custom.
5. Choose the dimension Instance.
6. Select your custom metric by its InstanceId and Metric Name.
7. View the graph of your metric.

```sh
mon-put-metric-alarm --alarm-name my-alarm \
--alarm-description "some desc" \
--metric-name CPUUtilization \
--namespace AWS/EC2 \
--statistic Average \
--period 60 --threshold 90 \
--comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold \
--dimensions InstanceId=i-abcdef \
--evaluation-periods 3 \
--unit Percent \
--alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:my-topic
```